# Deactivate two buttons until submit is clicked

Tags: javascript, forms, button, dom-events

I need to know how can I deactivate two buttons until the submit button is clicked.. I am using a Javascript code which deactivate the another two but not work.

Here is my form:

```
<form name="receta" id="receta" method="post">
    <div class="row-fluid grid">
        <div class="span4">
            <label><b>Lugar: </b></label>
            <input type="text" class="input-block-level" value="" name="lugar" />
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <label><b>Nombre : </b></label>
            <input type="text" class="input-block-level" value="" name="nombre" />
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <label><b>Edad : </b></label>
            <input type="text" class="span4" value="" name="edad" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid grid">
        <div class="span4">
            <b>Pr&oacute;xima cita : </b>
            Ejemplo: En 5 semanas &oacute; 30 d&iacute;as.....
                <input class="input-block-level" name="receta" maxlength="50" value="" />      
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="row-fluid grid">
        <div class="span4">
    <button class="btn btn-inverse" type="submit" name="enviar" id="boton1" onclick="boton(this)">
         <i class="icon icon-save icon-white"></i> 
        <?php echo $translate->__('Save Prescription'); ?>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="span4">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="receta_edit.php" type="button" id="boton2" onclick="boton(this)" >
        <i class="icon icon-edit icon-white"></i> 
        <?php echo $translate->__('Edit Previous Prescription'); ?>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="span4">
    <a class="btn btn-info" href="imprecetahoy.php" type="button" id="boton2" target="popup" onClick="window.open(this.href, this.target, 'scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=no,width=parent,height=parent'); return false;" onclick="boton(this)">
    <i class=" icon-print icon-white"></i>
    <?php echo $translate->__('View/Print last Prescription'); ?>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

and this is the Javascript I try to use:

```
<script>
    function boton (obj)
    {
        if(obj.value=='boton 1')
        { document.getElementById('boton1').disabled="false";
        }
        if(obj.value=='boton 2')
        { document.getElementById('boton2').disabled="true";
        }
    }
</script>
```

here is the script in jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/HDx8E/

Comment: There's only one button in this example. Do you want to disable the links (Edit/Print) until Save is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found some code which works for me. here the code:

```
<div class="span4">
        <button class="positive btn btn-inverse" type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" onclick="document.getElementById('edit').disabled=false;document.getElementById('imp').disabled=false;button(this);">
            <i class="icon icon-save icon-white"></i> 
            <?php echo $translate->__('Save Prescription'); ?>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <button class="negative btn btn-primary"  onclick="location.href='receta_edit.php" id="edit" disabled >
            <i class="icon icon-edit icon-white"></i> 
            <?php echo $translate->__('Edit Previous Prescription'); ?>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <button class="negative btn btn-info" onClick="myPopup()" id="imp" disabled >
            <i class=" icon-print icon-white"></i>
            <?php echo $translate->__('View/Print last Prescription'); ?>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

right now with this code the buttons (edit and print) are activated until the save button is clicked, the save button saved the data in the form and the other two buttons show the data already saved, the only error is this:

```
ReferenceError: button is not defined
```

and the error is when was clicked the save button in the property onclick: `onclick="document.getElementById('edit').disabled=false;document.getElementById('imp').disabled=false;button(this);"`

this part is the "not defined" `button(this);` ,  right now I don't know how fix it...

for last I would like to disable the save button when was clicked...but I don't know how do that...

anyway if this code helps you, be my guess.

sorry for my poor english, but like always I said is not my mother language and I tried to do my best in explain me in english

Kind regards!

Andres

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question.  Your script only does the following:

- if `boton1` is clicked, disable it.
- if `boton2` is clicked, enabled it.

In other words, when you click the submit button, you disable the submit button.  This has nothing to do with your intent as I understand it.

Forgive me; I don't understand Spanish.  However it seems like what you want is for the following two elements to be deactivated until your `submit` is clicked (which is `boton1`).

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="receta_edit.php"  id="boton2" onclick="boton(this)" >

<a class="btn btn-info" href="imprecetahoy.php" target="popup" 
    onClick="window.open(this.href, this.target, 'scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,
    menubar=no,status=no,width=parent,height=parent'); return false;"  
    id="boton2" onclick="boton(this)">
```

The problem here is that both of these links have the same id (`boton2`).  You should rename them to be unique, and preferably something more meaningful, such as `receta_edit_link` and `imprecetahoy_link`.

Then, you can disable both of these when the page loads and only enable them when the submit button is clicked with something like the following:

```
<script>
    function boton(obj) {
        if(obj.value == 'boton1') {
            document.getElementById('receta_edit_link').disabled='true';
            document.getElementById('imprecetahoy_link').disabled='true';
        }
    }
</script>
```